# how to initialize multiple app in firebase admin

Tags: node.js, nestjs, firebase-admin

I am new to firebase cloud messaging and i am practicing it on node js and i found that we can initialize more than one app on same project . I want to know up to how many  app can we  initialize in one project

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you share your existing code where you initialise one default Admin instance?

Comment: Actually i do it by providing name to each admin instance when i call admin.initialize app and  i wanna know how many app can i initialize by giving custom name . P.S the apps got initialized in runtime with dynamic name.

Answer (score 2):

> How to initialise multiple apps in Firebase Admin SDK

There is a specific [section](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize-multiple-apps) in the doc for this case. It shows the following code:

```js
// Initialize the default app
initializeApp(defaultAppConfig);

// Initialize another app with a different config
var otherApp = initializeApp(otherAppConfig, 'other');

console.log(getApp().name);  // '[DEFAULT]'
console.log(otherApp.name);     // 'other'

// Use the shorthand notation to retrieve the default app's services
const defaultAuth = getAuth();
const defaultDatabase = getDatabase();

// Use the otherApp variable to retrieve the other app's services
const otherAuth = getAuth(otherApp);
const otherDatabase = getDatabase(otherApp);
```

> I want to know up to how many app can we initialize in one project

I don’t have the answer to this question (i.e. I don’t know about any such limit) but you can initialise more than two apps.

Comment: For #2) There is no documented limit on how many app instances you can initialize, nor is there a limit hard-coded into the SDKs or back-ends. There probably is a physical limit, but nothing is imposed by the Firebase SDKs (that I know of).